# Adding a label to the left and to the right of a bar in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, label

I have a normal vertical bar chart in highcharts with 2 bars. These have a dataLabel each. I am able to display the datalabels in the (vertical) middle of the bar fairly easy.

My issue is that I need to have the left bar display the label left of that bar (outside the bar, on the chart, giving about 5px padding between the label and the bar).

I need the same with the right bar, except being on the other side.

I have tried doing something like

```
$("#id").find(".highcharts-data-labels text");
```

//... loop and then

```
var newattrx = parseInt($(textElement).attr("x")) + 70;
$(textElement).attr("x", newattrx);
```

But this works really sloppy and only for the display to the right.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jj14a1ny/

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better approach out there, but I'll put this here in case nobody posts one.

Using your existing method, you can do a check for which label you are processing, and specify the offset as positive or negative accordingly:

```
var x = i == 0 ? -75 : +75;
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jj14a1ny/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks, yet I need to add a label in of text, which I don't quite know the exact length of (It could be 'Income', it could be 'Special income return value'). Hence the issue. Will it be best to try use Js/JQ to work this out, and then manually adjust everyone by a loop?

Comment: So maybe better is use [renderer text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) and [getBBox](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.getBBox) to print custom text ?